Formula to Get nth to Last in Comma Separated List
I have a column with cells that contain months separated with commas. I need to return the nth from last month.
Example dataset:



Months
Nth from Last
Result




2024 May, 2023 October, 2023 May
2
2023 October


2023 October, 2023 August, 2023 May, 2023 January
3
2023 August


2024 March, 2024 February
2
2024 March



So based on the Months column I want to return the nth value (defined in the Nth from Last column) on the Result column. Note, this is looking from oldest to newest with the cells organized from newest to oldest. This will always be the case.


You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,choosecols(split(Σ,", ",),-offset(Σ,,1)))))


If you just want a single-cell formula, it would be:
=choosecols(split(A2,", ",),-B2)


Thanks for the single-cell formula. The formula picks the correct value, but the result is a date like 05/01/2024. I'd like for it to stay as text like 2024 May. I will be using this as part of a larger formula that will eventually xlookup on a column that has text values for the months.

wrap the whole formula within to_text() and try...

That did it. Thanks for the quick response.
